# CSS is not working while reducing the browser window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create star rating form in HTML/CSS which looks like below image1. But when we reduce the browser size the "star" is getting converted into the radio button.
NOTE:- When we move the app.css styling into the same file as a inline CSS it works fine.
Here is my code-
**rating.html**-

```
<label class="text-indigo-600">How was the video?</label>
            <div id="ratingForm" class="form-group col-lg-12">
              <input type = "radio" id = "VIDEOQUALITY5" name = "VIDEOQUALITY" class= "star star-5" value=5 >
              <label class = "star star-5" for="VIDEOQUALITY5" ></label>
              <input type = "radio" id = "VIDEOQUALITY4" name = "VIDEOQUALITY" class= "star star-4" value=4 >
              <label class = "star star-4" for="VIDEOQUALITY4" ></label>
              <input type = "radio" id = "VIDEOQUALITY3" name = "VIDEOQUALITY" class= "star star-3" value=3 > 
              <label class = "star star-3" for="VIDEOQUALITY3" ></label>
              <input type = "radio" id = "VIDEOQUALITY2" name = "VIDEOQUALITY" class= "star star-2" value=2 > 
              <label class = "star star-2" for="VIDEOQUALITY2" ></label>
              <input type = "radio" id = "VIDEOQUALITY1" name = "VIDEOQUALITY" class= "star star-1" value=1 > 
              <label class = "star star-1" for="VIDEOQUALITY1" ></label>
            </div>
```

**app.css-**

```
div.stars {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
 
  input.star {
    display: none;
  } 
  
  label.star {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: grey;
    transition: all .2s;
  }
  
  input.star:checked~label.star:before {
    content: '\2605';
    color: #FD4;
    transition: all .25s;
  }
  
  input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
    color: #FE7;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
  }
  
  input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
    color: #F62;
  }
  
  label.star:hover {
    transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  label.star:before {
    content: '\2605';
  }
```

[Actual form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueiye.png)

[When we reduce the Browser window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb1Sz.png)

Comment: Can you add snippet / jsfiddle link that could reproduce your problems? The code seems fine when I tried it

Comment: Works fine for me too, on all sorts of sizes.

Comment: Thanks @Kyojimaru and  @ A Haworth, When I split my code into jsfiddle it works fine. Also, my app.css have around 70 K line of code. Is it causing the problem? not sure

Comment: @DhananjayGour perhaps you can `inspect` the element, and check what style that's applied to the `ratingForm` when the browser is resized, maybe there's another style being applied on certain `width` using media queries